# Como eliminar textos entre parênteses com regExp?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em HTML5 que utiliza a API da Wikipédia para dar a definição do que pedimos. Usei o código que disponibilizaram em um fórum de outra língua do Stack e, nele, percebi a presença do uso de expressões regulares para eliminar certas partes do texto extraído (links, referências, tags, etc.).

Porém, eu gostaria de remover também textos entre parênteses como no exemplo abaixo:

**O que ficasse assim**

> Software aplicativo (aplicativo ou aplicação) é um programa de computador que tem por objetivo ajudar o seu usuário a desempenhar...

**Ficaria assim**

> Software aplicativo é um programa de computador que tem por objetivo ajudar o seu usuário a desempenhar...

Pois bem, tenho o código abaixo e gostaria de uma ajuda na parte das expressões regulares (que ainda não aprendi, mas tô tentando) para resolver meu problema:

```js
if(d.getElementById('q').value !== "") {
algo = d.getElementById('q').value
}
var definir = function(algo) {
startFetch(algo, 1, 1000);
d.getElementById("feedback").value = "Definir > " + algo; // Palavra ou sentença a ser definida
d.getElementById('q').value = algo;
search();
d.getElementById("resposta").value = "Só um momento...";
voz();
}

var textbox = d.getElementById("resposta");
var tempscript = null, minchars, maxchars, attempts;

function startFetch(algo, minimumCharacters, maximumCharacters, isRetry) {
if (tempscript) return;
if (!isRetry) {attempts = 0;
minchars = minimumCharacters;
maxchars = maximumCharacters;
}

tempscript = d.createElement("script");
tempscript.type = "text/javascript";
tempscript.id = "tempscript";
tempscript.src = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles="
+ algo // Palavra ou sentença a ser definida
+ "&redirects="
+ "&prop=extracts"
+ "&exchars="
+ maxchars // Máximo de caracteres a ser "puxado"
+ "&exintro"
+ "&format=json"
+ "&callback=onFetchComplete"
+ "&requestid="
+ Math.floor(Math.random()*999999).toString();
d.body.appendChild(tempscript);
}

function onFetchComplete(data, algo) {
d.body.removeChild(tempscript);
tempscript = null
var s = getFirstProp(data.query.pages).extract;
s = htmlDecode(stripTags(s));
if (s.length > minchars || attempts++ > 5) {
d.getElementById("resposta").value = s;
d.getElementById("feedback").value = "Definindo...";
voz(); // Lê em voz alta a definição da palavra ou sentença
espera(); // Delay para se aproximar do carregamento do áudio
d.getElementById("log").value += "Definir > "
+ algo // Palavra ou sentença a ser definida
+ "\n"
+ s // Definição carregada
+ "\n\n";
saveHist(); // Salva a definição no log de conversa
}

else {
d.getElementById('resposta').value = "Não encontrei a definição, "+nomeDoUsuario+".";
voz();
}
}
function getFirstProp(obj) {
for (var i in obj) return obj[i];
}
function stripTags(s) {

// Abaixo está meu problema ***************************************************
return s.replace(/<\w+(\s+("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])+)?>|<\/\w+>/gi, "");
// Acima está meu problema ****************************************************

}
function htmlDecode(input){
var e = document.createElement("div"); e.innerHTML = input; return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vejo que na tua regex já tens outros casos que queres tratar. Sugiro juntares `(\s\(.*?\))|` no inicio da tua regex.

Eu costumo [usar este site](http://regex101.com/r/hL3eJ8/1) para trabalhar com regex, é muito util.

De qualquer maneira o que esta sugestão faz é:

O parêntese exterior cria um grupo de captura `(...)`. Depois de abrir esse grupo de captura juntei "um espaço em branco" que se escreve com `\s`. Isto porque antes de um parêntese há sempre um espaço em branco. Numa regex quando se usa a barra `\` isso escapa o próximo caractere. Como viste antes os parenteses têm uma função num regex (grupo de captura), a barra `\(` "desliga" essa função e aponta para o próprio caractere `(`.

Depois uso `.*?` que quer dizer qualquer caractere, zero ou mais vezes, excepto novas linhas. E termino com `|` que é o "ou" da regex e que quer dizer `caso A | caso B | caso C` (caso A **ou** caso B, etc)

```js
var s = 'Software aplicativo (aplicativo ou aplicação) é um programa de computador que tem por objetivo ajudar o seu usuário a desempenhar..';
document.body.innerHTML = s.replace(/(\s\(.*?\))|<\w+(\s+("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])+)?>|<\/\w+>/gi, '');
```

Comment: Era exatamente disso que eu precisava. Resposta muito bem explicada, aprendi aqui o que venho tentando aprender há muito tempo. Muito obrigado, @Sergio.

Comment: @VictorRibeiro ótimo! Fico contente de ter ajudado. Votei `+1` na sua pergunta também por ter dado exemplo do que procurava.